# Vector of pairs with generic vector and pair type, template of template

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, vector, template-templates

I'd like to pass a vector of pairs to a function. The actual vector implementation as well as the types of the pair should be a template parameter.

I thought of something like this:

```
template<uint8_t t_k,
        typename t_bv,
        typename t_rank,
        template <template <template<typename t_x,
                                     typename t_y> class std::pair>
                  typename t_vector>> typename t_vector>
```

The first 3 are other template parameters. The last template parameter should allow to pass a `vector` (`std` or `stxxl:vector`) of `std::pair` with either `uint32_t` or `uint64_t` as type of the `pair.first` and `pair.second`.

Comment: Or you could allow any type as long as it has the methods you require (e.g. `vec.begin()`, `vec.end()`, `vec.begin().first/second` etc.)

Comment: Define "actual vector implementation".

Comment: yes for the vector any type would be fine I'd just like to specify the typename and that it has a type parameter std::pair, which has type parameter with typename t_x and t_y

Comment: You've named a template parameter `std::pair` which is not a valid identifier (that 4th template parameter is just gibberish).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this:

```
template<typename X,
         typename Y,
         template<typename, typename> class Pair,
         template<typename...> class Vector>
void fun(Vector<Pair<X, Y>> vec)
{
     //...
}
```

Comment: @JanB What compiler do you use?

Comment: thanks a lot. It works perfectly and is easier than I thought. I use gcc 4.9.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to have a **function that takes `std::vector` of generic `std::pair`**. Here you go:

```
template <typename First, typename Second>
void function(std::vector< std::pair<First,Second> > vector_of_pairs)
{
  ...
}
```

---

EDIT: If you want to take both `std::vector` and `stxxl::vector`, you can use *template template parameters* with c++11's *variadic templates* (since `std::vector` and `stxxl::vector` **have different number of template parameters**):

```
template <typename First,
          typename Second,
          template <typename...> class AnyVector,
          typename... OtherStuff>
          void function(AnyVector<std::pair<First,Second>, OtherStuff...> vector_of_pairs)
          {
              /*...*/
          }
```

Comment: "should allow to pass a vector (std or stxxl:vector)" -- Your answer prevents using anything except `std::vector`.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Edited

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your requirements but... what about the following example?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <deque>

template <typename P1, typename P2, template<typename...> class Vect>
std::size_t func (const Vect<std::pair<P1, P2>> & v)
 { return v.size(); }

int main()
 {
   std::vector<std::pair<int, long>> v1{ {1, 1L}, {2, 2L}, {3, 3L} };
   std::deque<std::pair<long, int>> v2{ {3L, 1}, {2L, 2} };

   std::cout << func(v1) << std::endl;
   std::cout << func(v2) << std::endl;

   return 0;
 }
```